# Docker pass variable without it getting expanded

Tags: docker

I want to run `echo "tools path is: $TOOLSPATH"` in my docker image but make sure the variable doesn't get expanded in my machine and sent to docker. I am not sure how to avoid variable expansion.

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/root -it --rm foobar echo 'tools path is: $TOOLSPATH'
> tools path is: $TOOLSPATH

docker run -v `pwd`:/root -it --rm foobar echo "tools path is: $TOOLSPATH"
> tools path is:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way to run `echo $VAR` inside the container and print it in your terminal. You just need to pass an *interpreter* too.

```
docker run alpine sh -c 'echo my HOME: $HOME'
my HOME: /root
```

PS: I used `alpine` as a test. If `sh` doesn't work, you can try `bash` instead.

Comment: The single quotes in your command are also important: the host shell will expand strings in double quotes, but not in a single-quoted string.  This causes the container `sh -c` command to receive the string containing the `$HOME` variable reference.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, @DavidMaze! Really helpful, if you want, feel free to edit my post to add this info too. No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/root -it --rm foobar echo "tools path is: $TOOLSPATH"
```